# PHP, PDF: split a large, single page PDF into another, multi- letter-size- page PDF

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, fpdf

I have a PDF of a sewing pattern. It's one page, 24"h x 96"l. The goal is to print it on as many letter size pages as it takes, to be reassembled for use in the real world.

In Foxit in Windows, there's an option to "Tile Large Pages" when printing, but the only way I've found to make that happen in linux is with pdfposter. It works okay, but the output isn't ideal, so I've decided to roll my own.

Using PHP's imagemagick extension, I can convert the PDF into an image and crop letter page-sized pieces out of it. Then I can use FPDF to take the cropped piece and plop it on a page. Repeat until I'm out of image.

Is this the way to proceed? Or is there a way to skip the imagemagick step? I've been all over the web, but I haven't found anyone else trying to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can import a PDF page into FPDF with [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/fpdi). The imported page can be scaled and resized as you would do with an image.

We (Setasign) don't have a demo for this task with FPDF/FPDI on our website but with SetaPDF. You can use the same logic with FPDF/FPDI. The demo can be found [here](https://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-core/demos/tile-page/#p-306).

Comment: That looks really good. Question: I would guess that useImportedPage is what I want to use, yes? x, y, width, height set the size of the "window" out of the large image I want, adjustpagesize = false so it keeps the scale. Do I have the right idea? (I can't find an explanation in the docs.)

Comment: Fixed format? No, but the final page size is dictated by the pattern: smaller people make for smaller patterns. I don't understand what you mean by "normal tiling ratio." Also, is my understanding of useImportedPage correct?

Comment: $adjustpagesize needs to be set to false, sure! The demo uses the origin page size for the resulting page size, yep I missed the 24"h x 96"l to letter thing.